# Function with multiple conditions if, else or ifelse

Tags: r, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

Im working with dive behavior, and then I have one function that create at data frame a new column with dial phases (day, dawn, night and dusk)  by the sun angle for each dive, but apparently the conditions they are overlapping each other. My real data frame have more than 90.000rows

(1) Dawn was classified by solar elevation from -12 to + 6 degrees in relation of the horizon, during sunrise, (2) Dusk was by solar elevation from +6 to -12 degrees at sunset. (3) Day was determined  when was greater than +6 degrees, and (4)Night less than -12 degrees.

```
dt = data.table(localtime= c("2016-10-24 12:45:06", "2016-10-24 12:46:13", "2016-10-24 12:47:02", "2016-10-24 12:48:27", "2016-10-24 12:52:39", "2016-10-24 12:55:11", "2016-10-30 21:08:02", "2016-10-30 21:18:27", "2016-10-30 21:30:13","2016-10-24 23:27:21", "2016-10-26 06:54:29"),
                lon = c(-39.94400, -39.94410, -39.94418, -39.94432, -39.94472, -39.94496, -40.87705, -40.87567, -40.87409, -40.00234, -40.59864),
DepthMean = 30, 50, 200, 76, 467, 87, 98, 10, 240, 176, 89))
```

```
dialphase <- function(df) {
  #loading the necessary package
  require(oce)
  
  #getting the sun angle from local time, longitude and latitude by the correction for atmospheric refraction
  x2<-sunAngle(df$localtime, df$lon, df$lon, useRefraction = TRUE)
  
  #converting into data.frame
  x3<-do.call(rbind, lapply(x2$altitude, as.data.frame))
  
  #creating new colum with the sun angles
  df$sun<- x3$`X[[i]]`
  
  #creating new column with only by hour about local time to do the next conditions
  df$hourBRT <- as.POSIXlt(df$localtime)$hour
  df <- df[!is.na(df$hourBRT),]
  
  #creating new column with dial phases by sun angles and hours with day, dawn, night and dusk
  df$dial_phase[df$sun >= 6.0] <- "day" 
  
  df$dial_phase[df$sun  < 6.0 & df$sun > -12.0 & df$hourBRT > 3] <- "dawn" #manhã
  
  df$dial_phase[df$sun <= -12.0] <- "night"
  
  df$dial_phase[df$sun < 6.0 & df$sun > -12.0 & df$hourBRT > 16 ] <- "dusk" #noite
  
  df$hourBRT<-NULL
  return(df)
}
```

I expected this:

```
dt
              localtime       lon     DepthMean       dial_phase
 1: 2016-10-24 12:45:06 -39.94400        30             day
 2: 2016-10-24 12:46:13 -39.94410        50             day
 3: 2016-10-24 12:47:02 -39.94418        200            day
 4: 2016-10-24 12:48:27 -39.94432        76             day
 5: 2016-10-24 12:52:39 -39.94472        467            day
 6: 2016-10-24 12:55:11 -39.94496        87             day
 7: 2016-10-30 21:08:02 -40.87705        98             dusk
 8: 2016-10-30 21:18:27 -40.87567        10             dusk
 9: 2016-10-30 21:30:13 -40.87409        240            dusk
10: 2016-10-24 23:27:21 -40.00234        176            night
11: 2016-10-26 06:54:29 -40.59864        89             dawn
>
```

And my guess is because the function gonna work right using `if`, `else` or `ifelse`, im correct? I dont have abilities with do function using these codes. Someone can help, please?

I tryed this things , but one phase is missing

```
> f1<-function(df) {
+   #loading the necessary package
+   require(oce)
+   
+   #getting the sun angle from local time, longitude and latitude by the correction for atmospheric refraction
+   x2<-sunAngle(df$localtime, df$lon, df$lon, useRefraction = TRUE)
+   
+   #converting into data.frame
+   x3<-do.call(rbind, lapply(x2$altitude, as.data.frame))
+   
+   #creating new colum with the sun angles
+   df$sun<- x3$`X[[i]]`
+   
+   #creating new column with only by hour about local time to do the next conditions
+   df$hourBRT <- as.POSIXlt(df$localtime)$hour
+   df <- df[!is.na(df$hourBRT),]
+   df$dial_phase <- with(df, ifelse(sun >= 6.0, "day", 
+                                    ifelse(sun  < 6.0 & sun > -12.0 & hourBRT > 3, "dawn", 
+                                           ifelse(sun <= -12.0, "night",
+                                                  ifelse(sun < 6.0 & sun > -12.0 & hourBRT > 16 , "dusk", NA_character_)))))
+   df
+ }
> g<-f1(df)
> table(df$dial_phase) ### dusk is missing 

 dawn   day night 
12185 46276 33593
```

** EDIT **

I guess my function its not ok, because when I plot, the dial phases overlapping, like this:

```
df$hourBRT <- as.POSIXlt(df$localtime)$hour
df <- df[!is.na(df$hourBRT),]
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(hourBRT), DepthMean, col = dial_phase)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600)) +
  xlab("Hour of the day") +
  ylab("Depth of Dives (m)")
```

[image]
Thank you!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: i will try, wait a minute

Comment: In the last part, you didn't update `with(df, ...` and is returning the original 'df' before that

Comment: I posted a solution below.  As there is no data, I couldn't test it, but I am guessing that it is in the right direction

Comment: i edited the post, see if  the df works, please

Comment: For me, based on the example showed, I get `1] "day" "day" "day" "day" "day" "day"` with `ifelse` on my post

Comment: here shows this error: Error in ifelse (sun <6 & sun> -12 & hourBRT> 16, "dusk"):
   missing "no" argument, no default

Comment: Are you using `with(df, ifelse(sun >= 6.0, "day", 
              ifelse(sun  < 6.0 & sun > -12.0 & hourBRT > 3, "dawn", 
                     ifelse(sun <= -12.0, "night",
                            ifelse(sun < 6.0 & sun > -12.0 & hourBRT > 16 , "dusk")))))`

Comment: no i tryed with your post, I put your example at my post now

Comment: I updated with the full function and the output i got.  Tried on both datasets and it is working for me

Comment: Hi...can you edit your question and keep only relevant details in it. The post is too long and with all the edits it is confusing to understand what is the final version that you are looking for. Please include 1 input with all the cases in it and show expected output for it.

Comment: ready @ronak shah!

Answer (score 0):

With the example you have provided, if you define your function `f1()` as follows:

```
f1<-function(df) {
   #loading the necessary package
   require(oce)
   
  #getting the sun angle from local time, longitude and latitude by the correction for atmospheric refraction
  df$sun <- sunAngle(df$localtime, df$lon, df$lon, useRefraction = TRUE)$altitude
  #creating new column with only by hour about local time to do the next conditions
  df$hourBRT <- as.POSIXlt(df$localtime)$hour
  df <- df[!is.na(df$hourBRT),]

   df$dial_phase <- with(df, ifelse(sun >= 6.0, "day", 
                                    ifelse(sun <= -12.0, "night",
                                           ifelse((sun  < 6.0 & sun > -12.0) & (hourBRT > 3 & hourBRT < 16), "dawn", "dusk")
                                           )
                                    )
                         )
 return(df)
}
```

You will obtain the same result than with your function `dialphase()`:

```
> dialphase(dt)
Loading required package: oce
Loading required package: gsw
Loading required package: testthat
              localtime       lon         sun dial_phase
 1: 2016-10-24 12:45:06 -39.94400  54.5839409        day
 2: 2016-10-24 12:46:13 -39.94410  54.7343935        day
 3: 2016-10-24 12:47:02 -39.94418  54.8437520        day
 4: 2016-10-24 12:48:27 -39.94432  55.0321025        day
 5: 2016-10-24 12:52:39 -39.94472  55.5801854        day
 6: 2016-10-24 12:55:11 -39.94496  55.9030545        day
 7: 2016-10-30 21:08:02 -40.87705   2.0214448       dusk
 8: 2016-10-30 21:18:27 -40.87567   0.4274248       dusk
 9: 2016-10-30 21:30:13 -40.87409  -2.2624818       dusk
10: 2016-10-24 23:27:21 -40.00234 -23.6748247      night
11: 2016-10-26 06:54:29 -40.59864  -8.4538891       dawn
> f1(dt)
              localtime       lon         sun hourBRT dial_phase
 1: 2016-10-24 12:45:06 -39.94400  54.5839409      12        day
 2: 2016-10-24 12:46:13 -39.94410  54.7343935      12        day
 3: 2016-10-24 12:47:02 -39.94418  54.8437520      12        day
 4: 2016-10-24 12:48:27 -39.94432  55.0321025      12        day
 5: 2016-10-24 12:52:39 -39.94472  55.5801854      12        day
 6: 2016-10-24 12:55:11 -39.94496  55.9030545      12        day
 7: 2016-10-30 21:08:02 -40.87705   2.0214448      21       dusk
 8: 2016-10-30 21:18:27 -40.87567   0.4274248      21       dusk
 9: 2016-10-30 21:30:13 -40.87409  -2.2624818      21       dusk
10: 2016-10-24 23:27:21 -40.00234 -23.6748247      23      night
11: 2016-10-26 06:54:29 -40.59864  -8.4538891       6       dawn
```

The result was not the same because, once your variable *hourBRT* was bigger than 3, the condition for *dawn* was satisfied, thus there was no need to evaluate for *dusk*.

That being said, I would rather use your original code in `dialphase()` than the nested *ifelse* structure in `f1()`. The readability in the latter is clearly worse and much more prone to errors. In that regard, you may find this reading interesting: https://medium.com/edge-coders/coding-tip-try-to-code-without-if-statements-d06799eed231

Comment: So, if I understand right, the original function is better, and I need change the condition? removing the variable `hourBRT` for evaluate `dusk`, like this ? `df$dial_phase[df$sun  < 6.0 & df$sun > -12.0 & df$hourBRT > 3] <- "dawn", 
  df$dial_phase[df$sun < 6.0 & df$sun > -12.0 ] <- "dusk" `. If I do this, dawn is missing

Comment: No. I meant that the function `f1()` was not working as `dialphase()` because of a bug when you provide the conditions for variable _hourBRT_. Then I gave you my opinion: in your case, `dialphase()` (without modifications)  is more readable and less prone to errors than `f1()` because of the absence of nested _ifelses_ (But it is just my opinion). I'm assuming that your function `dialpahse()` does the job you wanted it to do without any errors; if that's not the case, please try to explain us more clearly what is the actual problem

Comment: Ah ok! I understand now! Thank you! I edited my post, added another variable, `DepthMean` (its dive behavior, and this function create the dial phases for each dive and location) and the chart code (from my original data, not from the example here) and the result of that. With this `DepthMean` variable, you can also plot this.

Comment: Three follow up questions: 1) How do you calculate `DepthMean`; 2) have you tried to test the function `f1()` from my solution to do your graph? 3) if so, does it change anything? In your graph, it seems the functions you are using are not working for some cases...

Comment: 1) The `DepthMean` is from satellite tracks raw data. 2) Yes, happen the same thing.. 3) Yes is this the exactly problem, they are overlapping, and I dont know if is because of the code or the conditions, because of this I thought that was better with if else, and etc..

Comment: At this point it is a bit complicated for me to help you without seeing either the actual data or a piece of data that may giving you problems. If you can give us access to your data we may come up with different solutions